# Apply multiple Datatemplates to listbox Itemtemplate based on data

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, datatemplate, windows-8.1, listboxitem

I'm sure this is simple but i just cant seem to figure out how to do it. Basicly i have a list of customers that comes from a azure mobile service database. so far everything works fine but I would like to set the item template for each item in a listbox based on the data. I have 2 templates, one for companies and on for just a person. My question is how to apply each one.

Templates

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CompanyItemTemplate">
    -------
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="CustomerItemTemplate">
    -------
</DataTemplate>
```

Code

```
CustomerListItems.ItemsSource = customeritems.OrderBy(customer => customer.CustomerName);

foreach (Customers customer in customeritems)
{
    if (customer.Company != "")
    {
        CustomerListItems.ItemTemplate = CompanyItemTemplate;
    }
    else
    {
        CustomerListItems.ItemTemplate = CustomerItemTemplate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [`DataTemplateSelector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to dynamically select the `DataTemplate` based on the data bound to your properties:

Sample code:

```
public class ImgStringTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
  public DataTemplate ImageTemplate { get; set; }
  public DataTemplate StringTemplate { get; set; }

  public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, 
    DependencyObject container)
  {
    String path = (string)item;
    String ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(path);
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(path) && ext == ".jpg")
      return ImageTemplate;
    return StringTemplate;
  }
}

  <Window.Resources>
    <local:RelativeToAbsolutePathConverter x:Key="relToAbsPathConverter" />

    <DataTemplate x:Key="stringTemplate">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="imageTemplate">
      <Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource relToAbsPathConverter}}" 
             Stretch="UniformToFill" Width="200"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <local:ImgStringTemplateSelector 
        ImageTemplate="{StaticResource imageTemplate}" 
        StringTemplate="{StaticResource stringTemplate}" 
        x:Key="imgStringTemplateSelector" />
  </Window.Resources>

  <Grid>
    <ListView ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=This, Path=PathCollection}" 
              ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource imgStringTemplateSelector}">
    </ListView>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```